# using redirect links with angularjs and prerender.io

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application, prerender, prerenderview

What I mean by redirect links are links that internally redirect as soon as the app is opened.

What page is captured by prerender.io ?
The page before or after the redirect.

Extra question:
What triggers prerender.io to know that the page has fully loaded ?

Answer (score 3):

Javascript redirects are not recommended when using Prerender.io for SEO.

If you are doing a redirect, you want Google and other crawlers to know about the redirect so they can update their index to point to the correct page. The Prerender server tries not to follow redirects and instead looks for the [prerender specific meta tags](https://prerender.io/getting-started#404s) in order to give you the chance to tell crawlers that they should update their index.

Extra answer: The Prerender server counts the number of requests in flight in order to try to tell when the page has fully loaded. If you would like more control over that, you can tell the Prerender server to wait by setting window.prerenderReady = false; when the page initially loads. Then, when all of your ajax calls are finished, set window.prerenderReady = true; and the Prerender server will save the static HTML at that point.

Send us an email directly if you have any other questions. We're happy to help!

Comment: Ok so if the redirect is triggered as the page is being loaded prerender.io catches the page after the 'js' redirect since it considers it as part of the loading, right ?

Comment: Yes, since PhantomJS doesn't fire anything saying that it's about to redirect due to a javascript redirect. If it's a server side redirect, the Prerender server sees that and does not follow the redirect, but returns the correct status code instead.